# X11 XQuartz can't find directory

Tags: x11

I downloaded [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org) and installed it.
After that, the include folder and lib folder can be found at '/opt/X11/include' and '/opt/X11/lib', respectively.

But the following error always pops up when I try to compile other libraries:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '­-I/opt/X11/include'
```

I'm sure this folder exists. What should I do?
The following is the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: You need to put a minus before it: `-­I/opt/X11/include`.

Comment: there is a minus before the letter I. I have updated, Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure no folder called `-I/opt/X11/include` exists.

Comment: I updated the screenshot of this folder

Comment: Show the full compilation command you're using, because the error message indicates that `­-I/opt/X11/include` is interpreted as a file, not as an option + value. Or do you have a (single) quotes around it?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used cmake-gui instead of cmake command, and this error goes away...